# firefox not executing submit after print

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, printing, submit

This script will print then submit the data.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#print").click(function() {
            $("#button").hide();  
            window.print();
            $("#posting").submit();
            alert("Your data succesfully stored! Thank You");
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome.
It also works with Firefox, BUT only if i cancel the print dialogue.
If i print the document (e.g. to pdf), it won't execute submit. Any ideas?
Using Firefox version 43

Comment: Try using `onbeforeprint` event